# How do I make a bot send a random online picture and quote using a command?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I'm trying to make the bot post a random picture from a public online image folder like Imgur or Google Photos along with a random quote using a command. I can't use local folders and directories because I'm writing the bot online. Any help would be appreciated! :)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please include your code, approaches and errors you face. You may also take a look at [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

With discord.py, you can just use a basic bot example (Just Google how to do one if you don't know, plenty of tutorials are awesome) + a list with links to imgur images which are randomly picked on command. Example:
**Note:** Needs to `import random`

```
@bot.command()
async def quote(ctx):
    quoteList = [] # Put your quotes here!
    linkList = [] # Put imgur image links here.
    await ctx.send(str(random.choice(quoteList), random.choice(linkList))
```

## Reference:

[random.choice()](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_random_choice.asp)

[discord.py docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html)

[Discord bot on Python tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nW8c7vT6Hl4)

Comment: When I put this code into my script and changed the placeholders for my own purposes, it makes a syntax error at the very bottom of my code and no matter what I do it won't go away. I thought it might've been because I put the quotes and image links in quotation marks, but I'm unsure. The code at the bottom, which is a callback to another file that keeps the code running on a hosting service, was completely fine and working before, so I'm a bit confused.